make tikzpicture option which carries over to custom commands - pgfkeys
I have made some custom commands for tikz that I want to provide global options for.
I know how to provide options locally to the commands from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730112/319072, but I would also like to introduce some options which can be applied to the whole tikzpicture environment which carry over to each of my custom commands.
For instance, I want to add my own scale to it, because the regular scale messes some things up.
Here is a MWE which shows syntax similar to what I am looking to achieve. Note that it currently does not work, even when the key family is set to tikz.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter


\pgfqkeys{/tikz}
  {
    myscale/.store in = \cmd@myscale
    ,default/.style = {myscale=1}
  }
  
\newcommand{\myCircle}[2][]{
% #1  - Options
% #2  - Origin
\pgfqkeys{/tikz}{default, #1}%
\draw ($\cmd@myscale*(#2)$) circle[radius=3.14159pt];
}

\newcommand{\myRectangle}[3][]{
% #1  - Options
% #2  - Lower left
% #3  - Upper right
\pgfqkeys{/tikz}{default, #1}%
\draw ($\cmd@myscale*(#2)$) rectangle ($\cmd@myscale*(#3)$);
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[myscale=2]
    \myCircle{3,1}
    \myRectangle{0,1}{3,2}

    \myRectangle[myscale=0.5]{-1,-1}{-4,-4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



maybe something with a \tikzset{}?

If you're injecting into /tikz you don't have to do .is family.

@Skillmon Thanks for letting me know, the output still isn't scaling though.

Yes, that's to be expected, I just corrected a minor (unrelated) flaw :) Another flaw is that default is not a good name inside the /tkiz path, whereas stuff beginning with my seems like a good idea (it's unlikely that you accidentally overwrite some TikZ internal stuff with name like that).

There are two different ways to set default values in key=value interfaces. One is to always set them before the key list. That's what you're doing with your default style.
The other approach is to use a group in your macro so that every option given in the optional argument is only applied locally to your macro and the group reverts those local changes. The disadvantage is that this makes a group necessary (though many things work just fine with a group there are some exceptions of things for which you might not want to include a group). The big advantage is that you can just take over the external state instead of enforcing a known default. Of course the two approaches can even be mixed (so putting a group around and setting a part of your keys locally in some default style or similar).
If you apply the group strategy things just work™.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/tikz}
  {
     myscale/.store in = \cmd@myscale
    ,myscale = 1 % set an initial value
  }
  
\newcommand{\myCircle}[2][]{%
% #1  - Options
% #2  - Origin
  \begingroup
    \pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}%
    \draw ($\cmd@myscale*(#2)$) circle[radius=3.14159pt];
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\myRectangle}[3][]{%
% #1  - Options
% #2  - Lower left
% #3  - Upper right
  \begingroup
    \pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}%
    \draw ($\cmd@myscale*(#2)$) rectangle ($\cmd@myscale*(#3)$);
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[myscale=2]
    \myCircle{3,1}
    \myRectangle{0,1}{3,2}

    \myRectangle[myscale=0.5]{-1,-1}{-4,-4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


It took me a little bit to understand what you were doing by grouping the code, but now I get it. It allows you to pass options locally without affecting the rest of the picture. Thanks for the technique!

@Jasper you're welcome :)
